# Created objects in Rspec test can be inspected but showing as blank? and !present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a really strange case I'm finding when I'm running `RSpec` tests.

After doing a `my_model = MyModel.create`, I can do a `my_model.inspect` and I will get all the create properties of that object, but when I do a `my_model.blank?` or `my_model.present?` it shows as `true` and `false` respectively

I can further demonstrate the strange behavior by doing a

```
find_test = MyModel.find(my_model.id)
```

And I get the same results - the object can be inspected, shows properties, but registers as blank and not present.

Really weird and I can't write a reliable test with this behavior. How can something so obviously "exist" but be both "blank" and not "present"?

Here is code showing the output in comments:

```
def self.find_or_create(id, current_user)
   cart = Cart.where(referral_guid: nil, id: id).first  

   if !priority_cart?(cart) && !current_user.nil?
        cart = Cart.where(referral_guid: current_user.referral_guid).order("id DESC").first
    end

    cart.update_cart_with_referral_guid(current_user) unless current_user.nil?
    cart = Cart.create unless cart
    ##### test 1 #####
    puts("cart.inspect: #{cart.inspect}") #<Cart id: 2, created_at: "2015-06-13 17:39:57", updated_at: "2015-06-13 17:39:57", price_total: nil, tax: nil, referral_guid: nil>
    puts("cart.present?: #{cart.present?}") #false
    puts("cart.blank?: #{cart.blank?}") #true

    ##### test 2 #####
    find_test = Cart.find(cart.id)

    puts("find_test.inspect: #{find_test.inspect}") #<Cart id: 2, created_at: "2015-06-13 17:39:57", updated_at: "2015-06-13 17:39:57", price_total: nil, tax: nil, referral_guid: nil>
    puts("find_test.present?: #{find_test.present?}") #false
    puts("find_test.blank?: #{find_test.blank?}") #true
    cart
end
```

Comment: Maybe you can post some of your rspec code.

Comment: @user1200990 The StackOverflow convention is to post example code as part of the question, not as a separate answer. I edited the question accordingly, but you should delete your separate answer. Also, this comment was asking for RSpec code and you posted some of your code under test.

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.find_or_create(id, current_user)
    cart = Cart.where(referral_guid: nil, id: id).first  
    if !priority_cart?(cart) && !current_user.nil?
        cart = Cart.where(referral_guid: current_user.referral_guid).order("id DESC").first
    end

    cart.update_cart_with_referral_guid(current_user) unless current_user.nil?
    cart = Cart.create unless cart
    ##### test 1 #####
    puts("cart.inspect: #{cart.inspect}") #<Cart id: 2, created_at: "2015-06-13 17:39:57", updated_at: "2015-06-13 17:39:57", price_total: nil, tax: nil, referral_guid: nil>
    puts("cart.present?: #{cart.present?}") #false
    puts("cart.blank?: #{cart.blank?}") #true

    ##### test 2 #####
    find_test = Cart.find(cart.id)

    puts("find_test.inspect: #{find_test.inspect}") #<Cart id: 2, created_at: "2015-06-13 17:39:57", updated_at: "2015-06-13 17:39:57", price_total: nil, tax: nil, referral_guid: nil>
    puts("find_test.present?: #{find_test.present?}") #false
    puts("find_test.blank?: #{find_test.blank?}") #true
    cart
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`blank?` is a Rails method defined as follows:

```
def blank?
  respond_to?(:empty?) ? !!empty? : !self
end
```

and `present?` is simply the inverse.

In other words, it's very much dependent on whether/how the model responds to the `empty?` method.

You haven't provided the definition for the `Cart` class and perhaps you're making use of some framework, but assuming this is some form of "shopping cart", it would be natural for it to have defined an `empty?` method which returns `true` if an only if it "contains" items. Since you just created the cart objects and haven't placed any items in it, it's natural that it would be "empty".

Comment: That was exactly the problem - great call.   I have this line in Cart.rb: delegate :empty?, to: :line_items and once I commented it out everything worked exactly as expected.    Big thanks!

Comment: @user1200990 Glad it helped. It would be great if you could delete your answer and accept/upvote this and any other answers you've received to other questions that have helped you.